# In SVM, what are the labels and how do you get them from the data?

Tags: svm, predictive-models, libsvm, scikit-learn

I'm working on a school project and have decided to use SVM for stock market prediction. I have a 1000x5 matrix of stock quotes containg data for open, close, high, low, volume data.

From what I know, the labels should consist of +1/-1, for either up or down. How do I get this label data?

I'm using python and I am somewhat lost. I'm ultimately trying to predict the stock price a few days out in the future, or at least one day out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding **"how do you get [the labels] from the data"**:

That's up to you -- you can define them any way you like, but you have to think about what would make sense.

In this context, you could define the label to be +1 if today's close is higher than yesterday's close (i.e. the price rose as measured close-to-close), and -1 otherwise.

If you did that, you could train your SVM to predict whether the stock market will rise or fall, i.e. whether tomorrow's label will be +1 or -1.

Your predictors for tomorrow's label could be, for example, today's label, today's volume, possibly some lagged values of the label and volume, the day of the week and the month of the year, to give a very simple example. I'm not saying this model will work well, but you can certainly play around with it.

Regarding **"trying to predict the stock price a few days out in the future"**:

The problem with what I described above is that, even if you manage to train a SVM that works well, it will only predict whether the market will rise or fall -- but not its exact value.

If you wanted to predict the exact stock price -- i.e., a continuous variable -- I think you'd have to use something other than a SVM.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have much knowledge about stock market prediction but for SVM, it can be used as classification or regression. For classification you need to have a dependent variable as categorical (or binary for two class classification), for regression you need to have a dependent variable as numeric. In this situation, you should have independent variables (or features) that define your dependent variable somewhat.

So you can ask these questions to yourself. What's your main reason? What do you want to predict/forecast or classify by the means of some variables in the stock market?

If you have a continuous dependent variable, you can classify it by doing some research.